# GTK+, сигнатура функции обратного вызова

Tags: c, windows, signal, gtk+

Никак не могу разобраться с сигнатурами функций обратного вызова, которые связываются с теми или иными сигналами.

Сперва я думал, что у каждого типа события имеется своя сигнатура функции, но покопавшись в различных источниках, я встретил разные виды функций для одних и тех же сигналов.

Затем я попробовал изменять сигнатуры - добавлял в функцию параметры разных типов...

И никаких предупреждений или сбоев не возникло.

Как работает эта магия?

PS. Вот пример кода, который просили в комментариях:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void func_1(void)
{
    abort();
}

gint func_2(void)
{
    abort();
    return 1;
}

// _int и _data можно менять местами, GTK при помощи какой-то магии
// использует _data правильно.
// Плюс, параметра _int вообще не должно быть среди параметров функции.
gboolean func_3(GtkWidget *_widget, gint _int, gpointer _data)
{
    gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(_widget), _data);
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("magic");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);

    //g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(func_1), NULL);
    //g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(func_2), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(func_3), "reset");

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Никаких ошибок нет. Все три варианта функции обратного вызова работают правильно.

Третий вариант функции работает даже при том условии, что возвращаемое значение не void, а в списке аргументов функции в любой позиции присутствует "левый" аргумент.

Comment: Эта магия называется define . Легко можно все переопределить.

Comment: Как сочитаются сигнатуры и сигналы? 8) это круглое и зелёное.. Преведите  пример описанного вами.. И сигнатура это декларация функции?

Comment: @Yaroslav, как define решает проблему несоответствия сигнатуры функции? Как функция, которая принимает указатель на функцию обратного вызова, разбирается с тем, каковы на самом деле типы параметров функции обратного вызова, каково их количество и порядок?

Comment: Покажите код, в котором у вас "никаких предупреждений или сбоев не возникло". Что-то с трудом верится. Если это действительно так, тогда покажите определение этих макро из вашего GTK.

Comment: `gtk_signal_connect` является устаревшей (deprecated) функцией и больше не должна использоваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде используется макро `G_CALLBACK`, которое внутри себя выполняет насильное явное приведение типа любого указателя на функцию к "правильному" типу `GCallback` (т.е. к `void (*) (void)`). Неудивительно, что компилятор не ругается.

Так как разные варианты коллбеков для разных сигналов требуют разных типов функций, авторам API не оставалось другого выбора, как только приводить все типы коллбеков к одному общему "универсальному" типу. Побочным эффектом этого приема является полная потеря диагностики от компилятора.

В данном случае тип `void (*) (void)` в контексте указателей на функции используется в той же роли, в которой используется тип `void *` для указателей на данные, т.е. как "указатель на что угодно".

В такой ситуации следить за правильностью предоставляемых коллбеков - ваша задача. Предоставите неправильный - поведение будет не определено.

Comment: Это все я понимаю, но ведь в моем примере третий вариант функции обрабатывается корректно, какие бы параметры мы туда не запихнули, и в каком порядке. А ведь порядок параметров функции на стеке зависит еще и от соглашения о вызове. Плюс, я не совсем понимаю, как в этом случае компилятор контролирует занесение параметров функции в стек и очистку стека...

Comment: @Максим Вам показалось, что все отрабатывается корректно. Поведение не определено. Неопределенное поведение может выглядеть на первый взгляд "корректно". Да и с чего вы взяли, что параметры лежат "на стеке"? Передача параметров через стек - это уже замшелая редкость.

Comment: Ну я предполагал, что это UB. Просто это приводится в примерах по изучения GTK. Очень странно выглядит и сбивает с толку...

Comment: Но я так и не понял, у каждого сигнала существует своя сигнатура для функции обратного вызова? И где можно посмотреть, как должна выглядеть сигнатура функции для связи с тем или иным сигналом?

Comment: @Максим UB является именно ваша манера подставлять "неправильные" функции в качестве коллбеков. Где вы такое видели в примерах по изучению? Если функция подставлена правильная, то никакого UB нет. А как должна выглядеть правильная функция для каждого сигнала можно посмотреть в документации: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html . Смотрите раздел Signals.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Где конкретно видел, уже и не помню, но видел точно.